# Error while scraping a particular information field of a product from e - commerce website using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I try to scraping detail information product from e-commerce shopee. I've successed to scraping information from search page, but when I try to scraping from product detail information I got failed. I want to try using selenium, but I don't get it. How to solve it?

I try scraping using python 3.6 and requests

This is my code

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5',
    'Referer': 'https://shopee.com.my/search?keyword=ws331c'
}

url = 'https://shopee.co.id/api/v2/search_items/?by=relevancy&keyword=ws331c&limit=50&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search'  
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers).json()

itemid = []
shopid = []
for item in r['items']:
    #print(item['itemid'], ' ', item['shopid'] ' ', item['price']/100000)
    itemid.append(item['itemid'])
    shopid.append(item['shopid'])

print(shopid[0])

url = ('https://shopee.co.id/api/v2/item/get?itemid={}&shopid={}').format(itemid[0], shopid[0])  
p = requests.get(url, headers = headers).json()

for detail in p['item']:
    print(detail['itemid'])
```

I want to get the item id from product detail information, but the output was

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(detail['itemid'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: It looks like you are just making a api request not scrapping using selenium or anything like that, can you just paste the output of print(p) ?

Comment: @Doodle can you teach me how to scrapping product information using selenium?

Comment: before we do anything first we need to solve this, can you just paste the output, maybe you don’t need selenium here

Comment: @Doodle I've tried to print it, and it works. So thanks a lot, but I do want to learn scraping using selenium. ^_^

Comment: `print(p['item']['itemid'])` this give the value `999125485`

Comment: @Doodle this is my output now
`item_id, price, sold, rating
999125485   420000.0   12 4.857143`

Comment: @Doodle maybe you can teach me how to scraping review from user using selenium